# Fail posting an IFTTT JSON from Arduino

Tags: ifttt

I'm trying to send a status message in JSON format, to a Google sheet using IFTTT and WebHook.

1. IFTTT recipe works OK while posting values to all of its 3 cells to Google sheet (`String` and `char` variables).
2. JSON message is not too long ( tried with a very short message ).
3. JSON is created using `ArduinoJSON` library, and get posted as a MQTT message as expected.
4. converting the `String` variable ( holds the JSON message ) into `char`, didn't send it either.

I'm guessing it has to be with sending a `JSON` format using IFTT + Webhooks.

Am I right? How can I overcome this?

**EDIT 1**

Explanation: `makeIFTTTRequest` gets a string as a parameter (checked - and work OK ) to send it to IFTTT.

`create_wakeStatus` generates that string in a JSON format (also checked - and sent as MQTT )

function 1: sending to IFTTT

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void makeIFTTTRequest(T1 val1, T2 val2, T3 val3)
{
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(server);

  WiFiClient client;
  int retries = 5;
  while (!!!client.connect(server, 80) && (retries-- > 0))
  {
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  if (!!!client.connected())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect...");
  }

  Serial.print("Request resource: ");
  Serial.println(resource);

  String jsonObject = String("{\"value1\":\"") + val1 + "\",\"value2\":\"" + val2 + "\",\"value3\":\"" + val3 + "\"}";

  client.println(String("POST ") + resource + " HTTP/1.1");
  client.println(String("Host: ") + server);
  client.println("Connection: close\r\nContent-Type: application/json");
  client.print("Content-Length: ");
  client.println(jsonObject.length());
  client.println();
  client.println(jsonObject);

  int timeout = 5 * 10; // 5 seconds
  while (!!!client.available() && (timeout-- > 0))
  {
    delay(100);
  }
  if (!!!client.available())
  {
    Serial.println("No response...");
  }
  while (client.available())
  {
    Serial.write(client.read());
  }

  Serial.println("\nclosing connection");
  client.stop();
}
```

function 2:

```cpp
String create_wakeStatus()
{
  StaticJsonDocument<300> doc;
  // Constansts
  doc["deviceName"] = go2sleep.WakeStatus.name;
  doc["bootCount"] = go2sleep.WakeStatus.bootCount;
  doc["forcedAwake"] = go2sleep.WakeStatus.awake_duration;

  // Per wake cycle
  doc["sleepDuration"] = go2sleep.sleepduration;
  doc["Wake"] = go2sleep.WakeStatus.wake_clock;
  doc["SleepStart"] = go2sleep.WakeStatus.startsleep_clock;
  doc["nextWake"] = go2sleep.WakeStatus.nextwake_clock;
  doc["RTCdrift"] = go2sleep.WakeStatus.drift_err;
  doc["WakeErr"] = go2sleep.WakeStatus.wake_err;

  String output;
  serializeJson(doc, output);
  return output;
}
```

**EDIT 2 **

function 3:

```cpp
void postWake()
{
  char a[250];
  String output = create_wakeStatus();
  output.toCharArray(a, output.length() + 1);
  // makeIFTTTRequest(output,"A","B"); once tried as String and once as char ... both failed
  // makeIFTTTRequest(a,"blabla","blabla"); 
  iot.pub_ext(a, true);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide details of what happens, I.e. all output logs and errors? Can you also show the code that calls those functions? You seem to be encoding JSON inside JSON? Also you should never compose JSON yourself by concatenation, always use existing JSON serialisation functions from libraries like you do in your second function.

Comment: @jcaron 1) what happens ? nothing get posted when to post with that String involved. 2) calling this function: see edit 2 ( `output` was placed inside `function 1`) 3) JSON inside JSON inside `function_1` was copied from a given example

Comment: The code outputs tons of logs and traces... having those logs and traces would be very useful to debug the issue. In the Arduino IDE, use the serial monitor (in the tools menu IIRC)